# Biopython code refactoring

Tags: python

I want to make function get_abstract, but i don't know what this can look like if the function must return idlist.

```
from Bio import Entrez, Medline, SeqIO


list_of_ids = []
Entrez.email = 'ski89@gmail.com'

handle_one = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term='e coli', 
                           retmode="text", retmax=100000)
record = Entrez.read(handle_one)
idlist = record["IdList"]
for ID in idlist:
    list_of_ids.append(ID)

    if len(list_of_ids) == 100000:
        handle_one = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term='e coli', 
                           retmode="text", retstart=100000, retmax=100000)
        record = Entrez.read(handle_one)
        idlist = record["IdList"]
        for ID in idlist:
            list_of_ids.append(ID)

            if len(list_of_ids) == 200000:
                handle_one = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term='e coli', 
                           retmode="text", retstart=200000, retmax=100000)
                record = Entrez.read(handle_one)
                idlist = record["IdList"]
                for ID in idlist:
                    list_of_ids.append(ID)
```

so the args will be the start and TERM:

```
get_abstracts(start,TERM): 
handle_one = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=TERM, 
                               retmode="text", retstart=start, retmax=100000)
                    record = Entrez.read(handle_one)
                    idlist = record["IdList"]
                    for ID in idlist:
                        list_of_ids.append(ID)
```

Can someone help refactor this? cheers

Comment: Do you really mean to have a `for` loop nested inside another `for` loop that both reuse the same variables?

Comment: This type of questions are more suited for code review SE. What is your bioinformatic question? Do you need a new method to do it? A faster one?

Comment: Refactoring is for speed up script. I dont know any alternatives for download  many abstracts. Selenium is slow. And wanna be better programmer , thats why I ask. I dont have any helper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample of code that should get you started.

I created a separate `get_abstracts` function.  Then that function get called repetitively until less than 100K ids are returned.  If you wanted to get fancy this whole process could be called as a recursive function but that seemed overly complex.

```
BUFFER_SIZE = 100000

def get_abstracts(start, term):
    """Get N number of records from Entrez
    :returns list: List of ids returned from search
    """
    handle_one = Entrez.esearch(db="pubmed", term=term, 
                       retmode="text", retstart=start, retmax=BUFFER_SIZE)
    record = Entrez.read(handle_one)
    idlist = record["IdList"]
    return idlist

list_of_ids = []
start_at = 0

# Iterate the search returning 100000
while true:
    ids = get_abstracts(start_at, 'e coli')

    list_of_ids.extend(ids)

    # Break if less than 100K results were returned 
    if len(ids) < BUFFER_SIZE:
        break
    start_at += BUFFER_SIZE

# Do something with list_of_ids
```